# How do I get a LinearLayout where the components are stacked on top of eachother in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, android-linearlayout, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a custom `JDialog`. I would like to have the components stacked on top of eachother with their preferred height, but the width should fill the container. Similar to [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) in Android. I want that the components keeps their preferred height when the window is resized.

From [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html):

> **Scenario:** You need to display a few components in a compact row at their natural size.
>
> Consider using a JPanel to group the components and using either the JPanel's default FlowLayout manager or the BoxLayout manager. SpringLayout is also good for this.

E.g. I would like to have a `JTextField` above a `JTabbedPane`. I have tried with all the suggested layout managers FlowLayout, BoxLayout, SpringLayout but they don't preserve the natural size of my components when the `JDialog` window get increased height.

Is there any Layout Manager in Java Swing that I can use for my situation?

Here is a small example that shows my problem with the Swing layouts:
[image: A Dialog]

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestDialog extends JDialog {

    public TestDialog() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        //setLayout(new SpringLayout());

        JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField();

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        
        panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        
        panel1.add(field2);
        panel2.add(field3);
        panel2.add(field4);
        
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.addTab("Tab 1", panel1);
        tabs.addTab("Tab 2", panel2);
        
        add(field1);
        add(tabs);
        
    //field1.setMaximumSize(field1.getPreferredSize());
    //SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(this.getContentPane(), 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2);
        
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with implementing my own **StackLayout**, the code is below. This is how the same application in my question look like. The components are stacked from top to bottom, and takes up the full width, similar to `LinearLayout` for Android.

[image: My Dialog using StackLayout]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

public class StackLayout implements LayoutManager {

    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        int maxWidth = parent.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);

        int y = insets.top;

        for(int n = 0; n < parent.getComponentCount(); n++) {
            Component c = parent.getComponent(n);
            int height = c.getPreferredSize().height;
            c.setBounds(0, y, maxWidth, height);

            y += height;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container c) {
        int sumHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = 0;

        for(int n = 0; n < c.getComponentCount(); n++) {
            Dimension preferredSize = c.getComponent(n).getPreferredSize();
            if(n == 0) {
                maxWidth = preferredSize.width;
            } else {
                maxWidth += preferredSize.width;
            }
            sumHeight += preferredSize.height;
        }

        // add the containers insets
        Insets insets = c.getInsets();
        sumHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom;
        maxWidth += insets.left + insets.right;

        return new Dimension(maxWidth, sumHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container c) {
        return minimumLayoutSize(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(String arg0, Component c) {}

    @Override
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component c) {}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to have a JTextField above a JTabbedPane. I have tried with all the suggested layout managers

A vertical BoxLayout should work fine. If the components grow when you increase the frame size then you may need to add:

```
textField.setMaximumSize( textField.getPreferredSize() );
tabbedPane.setMaximumSize( tabbedPane.getPreferredSize() );
```

If you need more help then post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Edit:

You need to specify your preferred size for text fields. This is done by using:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

Comment: I have updated my question with a simple example now. I tried `setMaximumSize()` as you suggested but it doesn't work good on an empty `JTextField` since it will be very small.

Comment: @Jonas you can use `setMinimumSize()` for an empty `JTextField`

Comment: @Jonas, unless you give the text field more information to work with it doesn't how many characters you expect to enter into the text field. See my edit for the solution.

Comment: @camickr: Thanks, that solves the problem with the height, but introduces a problem with the width. I would like that the components can have any width, since that makes sense for a `JTextField`. I would like to have something that is simple in other frameworks e.g. `LinearLayout` in Android and maybe `StackPanel` in WPF.

Comment: @Jonas, I don't understand your requirement. First you said you DON'T want the component to resize. Now you say the text field can have any width. You can change the "10" when you create the text field to be any number you want. Or you can change the maximum size to use the "preferred height" and whatever maximum width you choose to use.

Comment: @camickr: Yes, I said wrong first. But I just want a simple layout where all components are stacked on top of eachother with their preferred height and the containers width filled up. I'm surprised how hard this is in Swing. Maybe GridBagLayout will do it, I will learn about it.

Comment: I got the layout I wanted with `textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, textField.getPreferredSize().height));`, thanks for the `setMaximumSize()`-suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The null layout (basically x/y) might be what you are looking for, or perhaps Group Layout.

MigLayout also does what you probably want out of the box (you have to give it a specific directive to grow with the window, otherwise it doesn't).

Conceptually I think you are confused by the fact that the layout ultimately decides the size of components, so the "natural" size is a bit misleading. I guess what you are after is the size as set on the component? Or perhaps you mean the default when none of the setSize methods have been called on the component?

Either way, with Swing you have to be more explicit in your sizing expectations to get good results.

Comment: I'm not confused, a `JTextField` that is twice as high as default makes no sense as long the text has the same size, see my updated question with an example. I will learn more about `GroupLayout` and MiGLayout, but I would prefere to solve this without third party libraries.

Comment: GroupLayout is not third party (although it is JDK 1.6). I think you are saying that you think that a JTextField should not fill such a large area, because you think the natural size is something sane. This is just not true. With JTextArea especially because it shares JTextComponent with JTextArea and JTextPane, it probably gets this behavior.

Comment: Yes, but for a `JTextField` this is an awful behaviour. I want a simple layout as `LinearLayout` for Android where all components are stacked on top of eachother with their preferred height, but they fill the conainers width. I'm surprised how hard this is in Swing.

Comment: When I try to use `GroupLayout` I get `IllegalStateException` for `JTextField` with the message: `is not attached to a horizontal group`. It seems to be hard to use the `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I quite didn't get what you meant by **natural** size of a component. But if you don't want the Layout manager messing up with the size of the components, i would suggest you use either the `setMaximumSize(int width,int height)` or set the layout to null and use `setBounds(int x,int y,int width,int height)` method to size your component.

If you are looking to tweak how the component's sizes change relative to each other, then i would suggest looking at GridBagLayout and using weightx and weighty properties.

Comment: I would prefere to not specify any numbers, that's one of the main reasons why I use layout managers at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GridBagLayout` and don't specify a fill or weight you should get what you want.  Essentially you will have a 1 column 2 row grid bag layout.  Just create your `GridBagConstraints` and set only the x and y options when adding the components - do not set any other options.

Comment: It works okay, but I have problem with using more than limited space. I have updated my question. I have tried to fill the containers width with `fill=HORIZONTAL` but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to add weightx=<not zero> to at least one component.

Comment: @shemnon: I tested that now, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a much simpler layout manager - BorderLayout() - from what you are describing. Code follows: you need to specify width of at least 1 JTextField to set up the width of the JDialog. You can use EmptyBorder if you want some spacings. Hope this helps, - M.S.

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestDialog extends JDialog {

```
private JTextField  field1 = new JTextField(20),
            field2 = new JTextField(),
            field3 = new JTextField(),
            field4 = new JTextField();

public TestDialog(Frame f) {
    super (f, "Test Dialog");
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout (new BorderLayout());
    cp.add (northPanel(), "North");
    cp.add (tabbedPane(), "Center");
    pack();
}

private JPanel northPanel () {
    JPanel nPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    nPanel.add (field1, "Center");
              // nPanel.setBorder (...);
    return nPanel;
}

private JTabbedPane tabbedPane () {
    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    tp.add ("Tab 1", panel1());
    tp.add ("Tab 2", panel2());
    return tp;
}


private JPanel panel1 () {
    JPanel tfPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tfPanel.add (field2, "North");
    return tfPanel;
}


private JPanel panel2 () {
    JPanel tfPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()),
           t2Panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    t2Panel.add (field3, "North");
    t2Panel.add (field4, "Center");
    tfPanel.add (t2Panel, "North");
    return tfPanel;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new TestDialog (null).setVisible (true);
```

}}